# How to make a Java Shell Command (NOT how to run a shell command with Java)

Tags: java, bash, shell, deployment, terminal

I just finished an terminal program and cannot figure out how I can properly deploy it so it can be executed as such via bash:

```
myjavaprogram [options]
```

At best, I can only seem to get

```
java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram [options]
```

to work. But this is insufficient. I'd like to give the program a clear name that I can quickly type. And before you say it, yes, I tried making a shell command already. It went as follows, and I named it what I wanted to name it:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram
```

I saved it to /usr/bin along with the other commands.

Problem is when I tried to run it, it wouldn't allow me to input options. Any advice from any java folks who have deployed a terminal application before? I don't want to have to type out the full path name each time I run the thing, as it is to be used for a very high volume purpose (lots of data crunching etc.). Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just change your script to `java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram $*` is maybe what you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't do it. The java program can't recognize any inputs when I'm doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. HTML screwup there. I meant to say I want it to run like "myjavaprogram [options]" I used angle brackets accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a a Bash solution, look into bash command line arguments.  Generally you would use $1, $2, $3 etc to specify options, so in your case, if you want 3 options you would write this.

```
java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram $1 $2 $3
```

and run it like so

```
my_prog 1 2 3
```

If you want to tell bash to process any other command line options given, use $@

```
java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram $@
```

and run it liks so

```
my_proc 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: So is there ever a reason I wouldn't just always use $@?

Comment: If you know your program takes a certain number of arguments, and you want to enforce only that number of arguments, you would want to use $1, $2, $3, etc.. whoever many you need.  If you don't need such a strict policy then you can use $@.

Comment: It is giving me errors that it does not give me when I simply do the java -jar /path/to/file method. i.e. it's giving me input errors about the options (the ones I set up myself in my java program) when I try to run the command this way. Doesn't happen when I do java -jar.

Comment: And sorry I didn't mention this but my program needs to recognize the options, so they are done with the normal dash notation. i.e. input is -i, output is -o, etc.

Comment: @TomBurns In that case you will either need to use a command line processing library in your java application (which is probably the best case), or use getops in Bash, but why would you do that if you can just do so in the Java program itself.

Comment: I've already done that. Used Apache CLI for handling command line input. The problem is not parsing the input. The problem is getting the input from the command line and giving it coherently to the program for processing. There seems to be a disconnect here so far between java and the command line. I simply want an alias for my program, like every other terminal program in existence. Shouldn't be a difficult thing.

Comment: @TomBurns Do the command line arguments got parsed when you do NOTrun the Java program in a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#! /bin/bash
exec java -jar /path/to/myjavaprogram "$@"
```

Notice the use of `exec` to discard `bash` and the quotes surrounding `$@` to preserve whitespaces.

### EDIT

Try this as your java program

```
public class T1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Have you printed the options received in your java program?

Comment: The option format is the same as those received by any linux terminal program. Think ls, cat, mkdir, cp, etc. etc. A dash and then a letter to signify certain options. That is how my options are fed to my program via the Apache CLI command line library, which parses those options so I can take the user input and process it accordingly. The problem is when I attempt to run this script, I get the error message that none of the options have been input, when they have, meaning there is some issue between the shell and java. My program is not getting fed the args[] input for parsing by CLI.